# rowspan in angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following table in an Angular 8 application where I am looping through some data and displaying the data in the table. In the table I want to use `rowspan` for "Status" and "Create Date" since these will always be the same. "Name" and "Amount" will differ so need different rows for them but a single entry for Status. I tried `rowspan="abc.length"` for  `{{data.status}}` but it does not work.

```html
<table class="table tableBorder table-responsive table w-100">
  <tr style="text-align: center;" class="bg-gray">
    <td class="w-12 bold text-left">Name</td>
    <td class="w-10 bold text-left">Amount (Rs.Cr.)</td>
    <td class="w-13 bold text-left">Status</td>
    <td class="w-8 bold text-left">Create Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of abc; let i = index">
    <td class="w-12 truncate-text ref-number-truncate line-height23">
      {{data.name}}
    </td>
    <td class="w-8 truncate-text">{{data.amount}}</td>
    <td class="w-13 truncate-text">{{data.status}}</td>
    <td class="w-10 truncate-text">{{data.createdDate}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yogesh, did u try the provided answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[attr.rowspan]`  as

```
<td [attr.rowspan]= "abc.length">
```